# Añadir los datos de Fecha y Encargado, en cada uno de los elementos que voy agregando en mis notas del Gestor de Notas

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un proyecto con *HTML*, *CSS* y *Javascript*. Es un gestor de tareas y de momento estoy pudiendo agregar la descripción de la actividad que es arrastrable a los estados de **Pendiente**, **En Proceso** o **Finalizado**.

Soy capaz de cargar los datos de fecha y actividad, sin embargo al crear la nota no aparece la fecha, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
/* crear actividad/tarea */
const tarea_submit = document.getElementById("tarea_submit");

tarea_submit.addEventListener("click", crearTarea);

function crearTarea() {
  const tarea_div = document.createElement("div");
  const input_val = document.getElementById("tarea_input").value;
  const input_fecha = document.getElementById("tarea_date").value;
  const txt = document.createTextNode(input_val);
  /*const fecha = document.createElement(input_fecha);*/

  tarea_div.appendChild(txt);
  /*tarea_div.appendChild(Date);*/
  tarea_div.classList.add("tarea");
  tarea_div.setAttribute("draggable", "true");

  /* crear span */
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  const span_txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.classList.add("cerrar");
  span.appendChild(span_txt);

  tarea_div.appendChild(span);

  pendiente.appendChild(tarea_div);

  span.addEventListener("click", () => {
    span.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  });
  //   console.log(tarea_div);

  tarea_div.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  tarea_div.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);

  document.getElementById("tarea_input").value = "";
  tarea_form.classList.remove("active");
  overlay.classList.remove("active");
}

const cerrar_btns = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

cerrar_btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```